# Show upcoming events - MYsql

Tags: mysql

I have a table which adds up events in the MySQL database, I need all upcoming events so for example today is 12/28/2016:2:37 pm  the query should return all the events post the current date and time.

I tried the following but sometimes the even time is wrong or the event month.

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `events` 
ORDER BY event_year DESC , event_day DESC , event_month DESC ,  `event_time` DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your columns are varchar, right?

Comment: create a `DATETIME`-type column (so you can sort on them directly), instead of storing these values seperately

Comment: Either order by cast of column to number or order by length(col), col

Comment: @Alfabravo 3 int and one varchar

Comment: What do you mean by "wrong"? Also, you should be sorting on `event_month` before `event_day`.

Comment: Well, @shmosel is right and the query is ordering by year - DAY - MONTH - time. Change the order and that will do. Also, @Wietse is right as well and you should store that info in a single `DATETIME` field so ordering would be pretty much straightforward.